# Wiki Parsoid error - cannot connect to Parsoid Server

Tags: wikimedia, parsoid

I'm trying to set Parsoid extension and Visual Editor on my wiki page. It is NOT on my localhost. Those who will use the Visual Editor must log in, but the content of the wiki can be read without logging in.

The address is http://contractor.bg/wikimedia/index.php?title=Main_Page

I downloaded the Parsoid extension (in the extension files there is no `settings.js` file, so I created it according to an example).

My settings are:

in the `LocalSettings.php` file:

```
require_once "$IP/extensions/VisualEditor/VisualEditor.php";
$wgDefaultUserOptions['visualeditor-enable'] = 1;
$wgHiddenPrefs[] = 'visualeditor-enable';
wfLoadExtension( 'Parsoid' );
$wgVisualEditorParsoidURL = 'http://contractor.bg:2083';
$wgVisualEditorParsoidPrefix = 'wikimedia';
//$wgSessionsInObjectCache = true;
//$wgVisualEditorParsoidForwardCookies = true;
//$wgVisualEditorParsoidTimeout = 120;
```

I tried with to uncomment the last lines, but it still does not work.

In the settings.js file:

```
 parsoidConfig.setMwApi( 'wikimedia', { uri: 'http://contractor.bg/wikimedia/api.php' } ); // I also tried setting an interwiki value, I am not quite sure what is the difference)
    parsoidConfig.serverPort = 2083;
    parsoidConfig.serverInterface = 'contractor.bg';
    parsoidConfig.strictSSL = false;
    parsoidConfig.allowCORS = 'contractor.bg/wikimedia'; // I also tried only contractor.bg)
```

At the moment when I try to Edit a page with the Visual Editor, I receive an error:

`Error loading data from server: 401: parsoidserver-http: HTTP 401. Would you like to retry?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsoid is not a MediaWiki extension (well, there was an extension with this name as a support mechanism for the actual Parsoid, but it was never standalone and is no longer required). It is an external service.

You need to actually start the Parsoid service by running `node bin/server.js` from the Parsoid directory. Ensure it is actually running on the port you specify in the VisualEditor config (2083) - it looks like you have something else there.

Comment: thank you for the answer!!! :) you are the first to spend time on my question. Unfortunately, my question is from July last year, so this project is long forgotten. However, you are kind of wright, as I failed running anything similar to Parsoid, so I solved the problem by writing additional code (which had nothing to do with Parsoid). Maybe, if I had tried your solution then, it would have helped! Thanks again!